# Loading the include file .ttinclude returned a null or empty string

Tags: c#

I have a C# project, and I have a `.ttinclude` file, which is a bit long to post here. Then, I have two `.tt` files, where I call my `.ttinclude` file. I have posted below the `.tt` file and the error message(s) that I get.

**ThisDoesNotWork.tt**

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ include file="ConfigurationTemplate.ttinclude" #>
<#+
    ConfigScope Scope = ConfigScope.Configuration;
    Field[] Fields = new Field[]
    {
        new Field { Name = "LTO", Type = "bool?", Key= "LinkTimeOptimization" },
        new Field { Name = "EmitDebug", Type = "bool?", Key= "DebugSymbols" },
        new Field { Name = "OptimizationLevel", Type = "Tools.Common.OptimizationLevel?", Key= "OptimizationLevel", Normalize = true },
        new Field { Name = "PlatformTarget", Type = typeof(string), Key= "PlatformTarget", Normalize = true },
    };
#>
```

I get the following error messages:

> Failed to resolve include text for file:The path
>   'C:\DirToConfig\ConfigurationTemplate.ttinclude' must be either local
>   to this computer or part of your trusted zone. If you have downloaded
>   this template, you may need to 'Unblock' it using the properties page
>   for the template file in File Explorer.

And the second error message is the one in the title of the question, namely:

> Loading the include file 'ConfigurationTemplate.ttinclude' returned a
>   null or empty string. The transformation will not be run.

Any ideas what the problem might be, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to "Unblock" your `ConfigurationTemplate.ttinclude`?
Just go to your windows explorer and right click at the file - properties --> Unblock

[image]